# How to convert an "attribute call" into a "method call" in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, beautifulsoup

From my understanding of OOP in Python, if there is no attribute named `xyz` on an object `a`, then invoking `a.xyz` raises "AttributeError."
But in beautifulsoup, if we call any arbitrary attribute on an object of type `Tag`, we always get some output.
For instance,

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
 
>>> html = requests.get("https://wwww.bing.com").text
>>> tag = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
>>> print(tag.title)             # makes sense
<title>Bing</title>
>>> print(tag.no_such_attrib)    # should throw AttributeError
None
```

[Here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find), it is
implied that `tag_obj.anything.something` gets executed as `tag_obj.find("anything").find("something")`. But I just can't imagine which type of construct transforms the former form into the later one.

Comment: A class can control what happens when you try to get an attribute from one of its instances, by defining the special `__getattr__` method. For example, you could write: `def __getattr__(self, attr):` `    try:` `        return super().__getattr__(attr)` `    except AttributeError:` `        return None`

Comment: Don't know why some of the code did not appear as code there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No imagination necessary. We can just look at the [source](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L1551): (abbreviated by me)

```py
class Tag(PageElement):
    ...

    def __getattr__(self, tag):
        """Calling tag.subtag is the same as calling tag.find(name="subtag")"""
        if not tag.startswith("__") and not tag == "contents":
            return self.find(tag)
        raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__, tag))
```

See the Python data model documentation for more information about [attribute access](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access).

Here is another very simple illustration of how you can override attribute access to get `None` instead of an `AttributeError`, when an attribute does not exist on an object:

```py
class Foo:
    def __getattr__(self, item: str):
        return self.__dict__.get(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    foo.bar = 1
    print(foo.bar)  # 1
    print(foo.baz)  # None
```

Making use of [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) defaulting to `None` here.

---

In short: Attribute access **is** a method call. Always. Though not always via the same method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with `getattr(obj,"no_such_attrib","xxx")` form?  xxx can be anything:  None, an empty dict, a default value.  Even another function call.  It needs no complicated `__getattr__` method and you can vary what you are up at the point of call.

So,yes `find_something()`.  Not sure if it gets called anyway if nothing is found (I assume so).  If that is undesirable, boolean short circuiting helps:

```
X = getattr(obj,"no_such_attrib",None) or find_something()
```

Within a an predefined set of classes, `__getattr__` is likely to be doing the job- as stated in DF’s answer- , as the *provider*. As a user, or just to avoid edge case work on your own classes for particular internal uses, `getattr` is low effort

(and avoids recursion errors that often whack you on `__getattr__`):

```
def __getattr__(self, attrname):
   " sloppy __getattr__ love recursion error :-( "

   if attrname = "missing_attribute"):
      return self.another_missing_attribute
   elif attrname = "another_missing_attribute"):
      return self.missing_attribute
   else:
      raise AttributeError(attrname)
```

Note:  similarly `dict` subclasses can implement `__missing__`.